# Window manager that will allow rules for specific applications?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager

When I have a second monitor attached to my laptop I always have two windows in the second monitor.  My console takes about 1/3 of the second monitor while Sublime text takes 2/3 of the second monitor.

What I would like to find is a tool that will allow me to hit a shortcut and have it take those two windows, where ever they are, and move them to the second monitor and size them correctly (regardless of what window I am currently on).

The closest I have found is [Breeze](http://www.autumnapps.com/breeze/).  Unfortunately Breeze requires that I select the window I want to resize and it only resizes on the current screen.  So if my console is on monitor #1, I have to manually move it to monitor #2 and then hit the shortcut.  Once I'm done with that I need to find Sublime Text and do the same.

Does anyone know of a tool that will do exactly what I need?

Answer (score 1):

[Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) can be triggered using keyboard shortcuts and can deal with external monitors.

It can also save snapshots of given window arrangements, which can be triggered either manually or automatically. You can trigger a snapshot from any window and it can save snapshots with up to 5 external monitors at the same time.

Here's a screencast by Don McAllister showing how this works: http://www.screencastsonline.com/mac/show/0333/